# How ARG definition works in Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

```
# Set to 497 by default, which is the groupID used by AWS Linux ECS instance
ARG DOCKER_GID=497

# Set default value of 497 if DOCKER_GID set to blank string by Docker compose
RUN groupadd -g ${DOCKER_GID} docker
```

---

With regards to second line(`RUN` instruction), expectation is to pick default group id 497, if group id value is not passed on command line.

[Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg) did not help answer this

`RUN groupadd -g ${DOCKER_GID:-497} docker` resolves this problem.

---

Why `RUN groupadd -g ${DOCKER_GID} docker` gives below error? despite `ARG DOCKER_GID=497` in Dockerfile...

`Service 'jenkins' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c groupadd -g ${DOCKER_GID} docker' returned a non-zero code: 3`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can just use `RUN groupadd -g ${DOCKER_GID} docker` and this will create a group `docker` with a GID `DOCKER_GID`.

You can check this quite fast by just building the following dockerfile.

```
FROM ubuntu
ARG DOCKER_GID=497
RUN groupadd -g ${DOCKER_GID} docker
```

Build two different images, one issuing `--build-arg DOCKER_GID=12345` and the other without a build arg. Run them and check `cat /etc/group | grep docker` that the GID is the one you are expecting.

Actually, just tested using `${DOCKER_GID:-497}` and it works just fine as well. So, what's actually your question?

Comment: My question is... Is it not redundant to mention `:-497` in my case? irrespective of value is passed at command line

Comment: @overexchange is it redundant indeed. You tried to use bash notation into a Dockerfile, which is not necessary given that a Dockerfile has its own methods to deal with default values.

Comment: I get error: `Service 'jenkins' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c groupadd -g ${DOCKER_GID} docker'` if I do not use `groupadd -g ${DOCKER_GID:-497} docker` syntax. Please respond

Comment: @overexchange you will need to provide your full Dockerfile if you want further help, because as I said in my answer, that syntax is just fine.

Comment: full docker file is here

Answer (score 1):

You have two option to declare ARGS in dockerfile.

**With some default value**

```
ARG DOCKER_GID=497
```

In this case, you do not need to double-check the value of `DOCKER_GID` as if you missed during build time it has default value that is `497`. so your RUN command will be

```
RUN groupadd -g ${DOCKER_GID} docker
```

**Without default value**

```
ARG DOCKER_GID
```

With the case, you have to use this RUN command.

```
RUN groupadd -g ${DOCKER_GID:-497} docker
```

As `DOCKER_GID` has no default value and if someone did not pass this value during build time it will assign `497` as a default value.

Comment: Check my comment in above answer

Comment: are you passing `DOCKER_GID` to build command? if not then its is expected.

Comment: What?   Am using **default value**... I already have `ARG DOCKER_GID=497` in Dockerfile. I don't need to pass through command line... Isn't it?

Comment: yes if its defined that you do not need passed. it should double check on your local system first, if it working on local something may wrong wtih jenkins.